# Comparing POSIXlt object with date string the right thing?

Tags: r, date, coercion, posixlt

I recently came across R code that compared a POSIXlt date object with a date string.

```
as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02") >= "2007-02-01"
[1] FALSE
```

The result, surprisingly at least for me, was  FALSE. I was expecting that the POSIXlt object would be coerced in to a character vector and so the inequality should test TRUE. I then tried explicit coercion and coercing either side in to the other's type yielded true.

```
as.character(as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02")) >= "2007-02-01"
[1] TRUE
```

and

```
as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02") >= as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-01")
[1] TRUE
```

I think coercing the LHS date object to a character vector is semantically wrong because the comparison then would be lexicographic which is not what is intended (although it evaluates to TRUE in this case). Am I right?

In my opinion third expression is semantically right code. But why does the first code not work (it evaluates to  FALSE)? Doesn't R coerce both sides to character vectors before comparing them?

Here's my platform information:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I am new to R. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Farhan

Comment: I thought I understood why but after looking at the code I'm now confused. It appears both arguments should be coerced to POSIXct but are not. Thought `Ops.POSIXt` would be called but now thinking  that since the comparison operators are Primitive that no class checking is done.

Comment: What version of R are you running? When I copy/paste `as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02") >= "2007-02-01"` into my R session i get `TRUE` (verision 3.1.1). @BondedDust at least for me, if I do `debugonce(Ops.POSIXt)` I can see that function is being called. OP, does `as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02")  == as.POSIXct("2007-02-02")` return `TRUE` for you? What is your `Sys.timezone()`?

Comment: I'm still using R 3.1.0 (Patched). I looked through the NEWS file and do not see where this was specifically reported as a bug or a fix. I was using trace() and did not see that `Ops.POSIXt` was called, but do see it appear with `debugonce`. Now I'm wondering if the second instance I see of `as.character(e1)` in the conditional before the operation on 'e2' was changed to `as.character(e2)` but not recorded in the NEWS file.

Comment: So the answer seems to be that ... no, the comparison is not done as a character, but as a numeric.... after both are coerced with as.POSIXct ... but only in the most up-to-date version of R. I can confirm that updating to 3.1.1 gives the expected answer: `> as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02") >= "2007-02-01" #
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust I'm using R 3.1.0. Is there any documentation on such conversion to POSIXct? I have not been able to find much information on coercion in general except for the precious few lines in the help pages. I quote them here.                            "If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of
precedence being character, complex, numeric, ..." and "At least  one of ‘x’ and ‘y’ must be an atomic vector, but if the
other is a list R attempts to coerce it to the type of the atomic
vector".

Comment: You did expect some sort of coercion and R does quite a bit of implicit coercion. There is some material as `?as` and more material at `?mode` if you are looking for material on general issues of coercion of R objects. I did not find much that was specific to `POSIXt` objects, so needed to go to the code, which in my case (and yours) was misleading. That doesn't usually happen to me. Usually going to the code clarifies things for me, unless it is in C-calls.

Answer (score 1):

In general, dates should all be of `class` *Date* when doing comparisons.

It works in some cases because R converts the String **"2007-02-01"** into a *Date* behind the scenes, which can fail in some cases:

```
as.Date("2020-09-12") <= "2020:09:13"
# Error in charToDate(x) : 
#   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Also, be aware of the different Date methods, which are incompatible:

```
as.POSIXlt("2007-02-02") <= as.Date("2020,01,12", "%Y,%m,%d")
#   sec    min   hour   mday    mon   year   wday   yday  isdst   zone gmtoff 
#  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE     NA     NA 
#Warning messages:
#1: Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for "<=" 
#2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

Btw, I can't reproduce the first example anymore (R version 4.0.3):

```
as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02") >= "2007-02-01"
# Error in as.POSIXlt.date("2007-02-02") : 
#   could not find function "as.POSIXlt.date"

as.POSIXlt.Date("2007-02-02") >= "2007-02-01"
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In as.POSIXlt.Date("2007-02-02") : NAs introduced by coercion
```